# Is it possible to link repeatable migrations to a specific target version?

Tags: flyway

Is it possible run a repeatable migration only when a specific target version is exceeded?

For example,
`Current version: 0.7.0`

```
V0.7.0__cars.sql  

CREATE TABLE cars (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    license_plate VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    color VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

R__Blue_cars.sql

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW blue_cars AS SELECT id, license_plate FROM cars WHERE color='blue';
```

Now if i run this migration in development, there are no problems. However if I try to migrate to a specific target on my staging/production instance, I run into trouble.

`flyway -target=0.5.0 migrate`

This migration includes `R__Blue_cars.sql`

Ideally I would want that repeatable migration to run for the first time only if `target >= 0.7.0`

Answer (score 0):

Flyway repeatable migrations do not have a version. Therefore by design, repeatable migrations cannot be selectively applied based on a target version. Also, repeatable migrations are applied only after all versioned migrations are done.